# Pandas, filtering with conditional statements

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe I need to filter based on a condition, sort of as below. Essentially, Filtering by the verified speed, unless it is equal to 0, then using the Speed column.

```
above_limit_speed = (df_cimbined_traff[df_cimbined_traff['Speed'] > df_cimbined_traff[df_cimbined_traff['Verified_speed']) > df_cimbined_traff['Postedspeed']].groupby('deploymentid')['Speed'].count().reset_index().rename(columns={'Speed': 'count_above_speed_limit'}).set_index('deploymentid')
```

Example Dataframe

```
X_value - Speed - Verified_Speed - Post Speed
bluergh - 50 - 51 - 49
blasdu - 50 - 0 - 30
ausdas - 60-60-40
```

I have tried the above, and variations of it, but am very confused about the best way to approach this problem in Python with Pandas.

### update

So basically,

I want to compare post speed to verified speed, unless that speed is equal to zero, where i want to compare it to speed instead.

Would appreciate help!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an example dataframe and your expected output

Comment: I don't understand which filters you want to apply. Can you please explain a little further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new column `prev_speed` with the logic you want

```
df['prev_speed'] = df.Verified_Speed
df.prev_speed.update(df.loc[df.prev_speed == 0, 'Speed'])
```